# XML Serialization of Point3d

Tags: vb.net

I tried searching the web to figure this out but it yielded no solution.

I'm trying to serialize a Point3d like the one below but when I try it doesn't produce any results in the XML file. This property is in a sub class of "ExClass".

```
Public Property Point As Point3d
```

Using

```
Dim w As TextWriter = New StringWriter
s = New XmlSerializer(GetType(ExClass), New Type() {GetType(Point3d)})
s.Serialize(w, aB)
w.Flush()
```

I get this type of output:

```
      <Angle>0</Angle>
      <Radii>0</Radii>
      <Point />
```

The Angle and Radii have their default values returned but the Point3d will never return a value.

Comment: Can you show us the definition of `Point3d`?

Comment: @VisualVincent Sorry I'm very new but what do you mean by definition? This is the Point3d that I'm using: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.point3d?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: 'Definition' is the code you used to create the class in the first place. However as you are using a built-in class and pointed me to the documentation that is no longer necessary. Unfortunately though I cannot see why it doesn't work properly, because there's nothing stopping it from being serialized.

Comment: @VisualVincent My usage looks more like the follow: `s = New XmlSerializer(GetType(ExClass), New Type() {GetType(SomeClass)})` Where SomeClass is a class that has the Point3d property. My doubles in that sub class are serialized properly but the Point3d always serializes with no value.

Comment: Yeah I got it, but it's strange because I cannot seem to find or figure out any reason as to why that happens.

Comment: @VisualVincent Actually "ExClass" has a property in it that is declared like this `Public Property someProperty As someClass()`. Inside of someClass() the Point3d property is defined. I'm still trying to play with it but I created 3 more doubles that hold the point3d values and they are serialized correctly. I'll let you know if I figure out the solution. Thank you so much for your help I really appreciate it.

Comment: I did a bit more digging and noticed my values in the Point3d are under "Non-Public Members" do you think this is why I'm unable to serialize them? I must have gave you the wrong definition. Here it is: https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2018/ENU/OARX-ManagedRefGuide/files/OREFNET-Autodesk-AutoCAD-Geometry-Point3d-html.html

My apologies for the wrong initial definition.

Comment: Well, yes. The XML Serializer can only serialize public members, but according to the documentation you linked to (assuming that's the exact `Point3D` that you're using) both X, Y and Z are public properties.

Comment: Ah, according to your new link X, Y and Z are all read-only. They must also be writable to be serialized. I suggest you create your own `Point3D` structure instead and just convert that to a `Point3d` when necessary.

Comment: Hi @VisualVincent thank you so much for the help. I will mark this as solved now. I have created my own structure as advised and it is working correctly now. Thanks!!!

Edit: How exactly do I mark this as solved? I don't see any buttons anywhere.